# Angular 2 Dialog won`t open

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I have a problem with the angular2 Dialog, befor i give you the error here is a snipet of my Code(i have exluced a lot, but i think they might not be important here)

signup.component.ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog} from '@angular/material';

import template from './signup.component.html';

@Component({
    selector: 'signup',
    template
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router, private zone: NgZone, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public dialog: MdDialog) {
    }
openDialog() {
        this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);
    }
@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
    templateUrl: './dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {}
```

signup.component.html file:

```
<h3 flex>Just<a (click)="openDialog()">Click here</a></h3>
```

and the dialog.html:

```
<p>pls work</p>
```

i get this error on the console in Chrome:
No component factory found for DialogOverviewExampleDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DialogOverviewExampleDialog` component must be declared in the `entryComponents` field of your NgModule. Otherwise, the angular compiler doesn't know that this component is displayed somewhere (since its selector isn't used in any template), and it's thus not compiled.

Comment: this might be me being stupid again, but where can i find the entryComponents?

Comment: In the object passed to `@NgModule()`. That's typically in the app.module.ts file.